# react-scripts 2.1.1 update fails

Tags: reactjs, babel-plugin, react-app-rewired

My task is to update "react-scripts" 2.1.1 in ReactJS app to something newer.
what I did:
1.

- clone clean project
- update
  "react-scripts": "2.1.1" -> "2.1.8"
- npm install
- npm start

First problem, which I faced:

> frontend@2.0.0 start C:\projects\reactjs-superapp
> react-app-rewired start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\projects\reactjs-superapp\node_modules\react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev'
Require stack:
C:\projects\reactjs-superapp\node_modules\react-app-rewired\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\reactjs-superapp\node_modules\react-app-rewired\scripts\start.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\projects\\reactjs-superapp\\node_modules\\react-app-rewired\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```

2. 

- update
  "react-app-rewired": "1.6.2" -> "2.0.3
- npm install
- npm start
  The "injectBabelPlugin" helper has been deprecated as of v2.0. You can use customize-cra plugins in replacement - https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra#available-plugins

3. 

- followed the solution found here https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/348 and replaced existing

  mofules.exports = function override (config, env) {
  ......
  }

to

```
module.exports = override(
    fixBabelImports("import", {
        libraryName: "antd", libraryDirectory: "es", style: true // change importing css to less
    }),
    addLessLoader({
        javascriptEnabled: true
    })
);
```

- added
  "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
  "postcss-normalize": "^9.0.0",
  "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2"
- npm install
- npm start

Now on starting there is a compilation error
./src/config/config.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/config/config.scss)
@import "~importConfigPath";
^
File to import not found or unreadable: ~importConfigPath.
in C:\projects\reactjs-superapp\src\config\config.scss (line 2, column 1)

which is probably expected. This ~importConfigPath was previously defined in module.exports function as following

```
 config.resolve = {
     modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
     extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
     alias: {
         ...config.resolve.alias,
         "importConfigPath": path.join(__dirname, 'src/view/styles/templates/' + findPara("THEME", "1") + '.scss'),
         "importVariablesPath": path.join(__dirname, 'src/view/styles/templates/' + findPara("THEME", "1") + "/colors.scss"),
     }
 };
```

Now it has to be defined in this new structure. This is where I am lost now. How to do it?